# Why blob url is not initialized and url is overlaped by other blob link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

### Problem

Hi I am making markdown texteditor and I am working on upload image by blob. It works fine at the first time, but when I paste another picture, blob link doesn't formatted correctly.

It looks like: `blob:http://localhost:3000/oi4fr-...blob:http://localhost:3000/b340-1204...`.

Even though I initialize blob, and blobURL variables, this keeps happening.
How can I solve this?

### code

```js
import markdownLinkExtractor from 'markdown-link-extractor'
import { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { ReactMarkdown } from 'react-markdown/lib/react-markdown'

export default function Home() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  const textArea = useRef(null)

  const handlePaste = async(e) => {
  if(!e.clipboardData.getData('text')){
  let blob = undefined
  let blobURL = ''
  const object = e.clipboardData.items;
  const items = [].slice.call(object).filter((obj)=> {
    // Filter the image items only
    return obj.type.indexOf('image' || 'image/png') !== -1;})
    const item = items[0];
    console.log(item)
    console.log(item.type)
    // Get the blob of image
    blob = await item.getAsFile();
    blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log("url", blobURL)
    textArea.current.addEventListener('paste', (e)=>{
      document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, blobURL)
    })
    }
}

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
      ref={textArea} 
      name="" 
      id="" 
      cols="30" 
      rows="10"
      value={input}
      onPaste={(e)=>handlePaste(e)}
      onChange={(e)=>setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <ReactMarkdown children={input}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new paste event listener every time, but you never remove the previous one. So the second time you paste, the previous listener will still insert the previous URL *and* the new listener will also insert the new URL after it, and so on.

You can use the `once` option to create a listener that gets automatically removed after it was called once, by passing `{ once: true }` as third argument to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thanks, nerver knew I can pass the third argument like that.